# Calculate an intersection point with python gets "nan"

Tags: python

i would like to calculate an intersection point with python like

> a*x^4 + b*x^3 + c*x^2 + d*x + e = A*x^2 + B*x

So I get the solution for x from https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a*x%5E4%2Bb*x%5E3%2Bc*x%5E2%2Bd*x+%2Be+%3D+A+*+x+%5E2+%2B+B+*+x (second solution)

When I test it without the comment add (+2.67E-05), it works. But when I add some constants like the comment, x is "nan". THE PROBLEM: In Excel, it works. There I have an solution (2394).

What is the problem in python? What is the difference between python and excel?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Apr 11 11:21:31 2022

"""

import numpy as np

def calc_intersection(a, b, c, d, e, A, B):
    x=-b/(4*a)-1/2*np.sqrt(b**2/(4*a**2)-(2*(c-A))/(3*a)+(2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e+np.sqrt((2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e)**2-4*((c-A)**2-3*b*(d-B)+12*a*e)**3))**(1/3)/(3*2**(1/3)*a)+(2**(1/3)*(A**2-2*c*A+c**2+3*b*B-3*b*d+12*a*e))/(3*a*(2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e+np.sqrt((2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e)**2-4*((c-A)**2-3*b*(d-B)+12*a*e)**3))**(1/3)))+1/2*np.sqrt(b**2/(2*a**2)-(4*(c-A))/(3*a)-(2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e+np.sqrt((2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e)**2-4*((c-A)**2-3*b*(d-B)+12*a*e)**3))**(1/3)/(3*2**(1/3)*a)-(2**(1/3)*(A**2-2*c*A+c**2+3*b*B-3*b*d+12*a*e))/(3*a*(2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e+np.sqrt((2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e)**2-4*((c-A)**2-3*b*(d-B)+12*a*e)**3))**(1/3))-(-b**3/a**3+(4*(c-A)*b)/a**2-(8*(d-B))/a)/(4*np.sqrt(b**2/(4*a**2)-(2*(c-A))/(3*a)+(2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e+np.sqrt((2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e)**2-4*((c-A)**2-3*b*(d-B)+12*a*e)**3))**(1/3)/(3*2**(1/3)*a)+(2**(1/3)*(A**2-2*c*A+c**2+3*b*B-3*b*d+12*a*e))/(3*a*(2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e+np.sqrt((2*(c-A)**3-9*b*(d-B)*(c-A)-72*a*e*(c-A)+27*a*(d-B)**2+27*b**2*e)**2-4*((c-A)**2-3*b*(d-B)+12*a*e)**3))**(1/3)))))
    return x


a = -2.8977E-13
b = 4.70219E-09
c = -2.40496E-05
d = 0.016186125
e = 217.0825374

A = 3.4770E-06 #+ 2.67E-05
B = 4.0566E-10

x = calc_intersection(a, b, c, d, e, A, B)
```

Comment: Maybe a is too close to zero?

Comment: but why i get in excel an (physically) right solution?

Comment: The equation is too complex to examine step by step.  But when I divide all parameters by `-1` or `a` (`b /= -1; c /= -1; d /= -1; e /= -1; A /= -1; B /= -1; a /= -1`) then I obtain `2394.2540563880266`.  From this my conjecture is that some parameters are too close to zero, which makes a negative number inside sqrt somewhere in the middle step, and generates an error.

Comment: This could happen if Excel and Python have different precision levels for floating numbers.

Comment: I also think that A gets too big and the argument in sqrt gets negative, because (c-A)...or so. Is dividing all parameters by -1 a solution? I don't know why it works here...